# Why copying a text box in Adobe Acrobat XI Pro does not appear in Ditto's clipboard history?

Tags: windows-7, pdf, adobe-acrobat, ditto

When I editing the content of a PDF using Adobe Acrobat XI Pro, I noticed that when I copy a text box object, it does not appear in Ditto's clipboard history. Why?

To edit the content of a PDF I use this mode:

[image]

Example of a text box object:

[image]

I use Adobe Acrobat XI Pro on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you mean by "when I could be a text box object" but if what you're trying to do is make the text inside the box appear on Ditto, then you have to select the text itself and copy it. If you simply select the box and then copy the box, you would be copying an Adobe Acrobat object and not the text inside it. Most likely, this box object cannot be understood by Ditto so it won't display it.

Comment: Thanks, any idea why Ditto doesn't handle Adobe objects?

Comment: Ditto supports text, images and html. An Adobe Acrobat box is none of those. You won't even be able to paste the box object on Microsoft Word. Most likely, Adobe Acrobat is the only software that supports them.

Comment: Also, its likely that since adobe acrobat is the only that supports this object, it doesn't send anything to the windows clipboard when you copy a box object.

Comment: Think of it this way: Notepad doesn't support images so you can't copy/paste them to it. Similarly, Ditto doesn't support Adobe Acrobat objects.

Comment: Good catch: Adobe doesn't send anything to the windows clipboard when a box object is copied.